# How to Remove Confirm Form Resubmission on Search Page

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Why i must to Confirm Form Resubmisson in search page where i go back from product page to search page. Because i just back to search page and didnt have form important in here. Please help me!!

I'm using Codeigniter Framework

This my Controller

```
public function search(){
            $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
            $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
            $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
            $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');

            $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
            $data['search_data']=$this->Product_model->get_product_keyword($keyword);
            $this->load->view('frontend/search_view',$data);
        }
```

This my Product_Model

```
public function get_product_keyword($keyword){
        $this->db->select('products.*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->join('products.category');
        $this->db->like('products.name',$keyword);
        $this->db->or_like('content',$keyword);
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

This My Search_View

```
<?php
  header('Cache-Control: no cache');
  session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');; 
  echo form_open('search'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="search">
    <input type="submit" name="search_submit" value="Cari">
  <?php echo form_close() ?>

  <table>

      <?php foreach($search_data as $men); { ?>
        <tr>
          <?php echo form_open('dashboard/beli');?>
          <td><?php echo ($men->name); ?></td>
          <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>


  </table>
```

Comment: why are you worried about that confirmation popup, that's the browser's feature btw

Comment: because its just search page, not a important form. and when i go back form product page to search page and i must confirm it its very annoyed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have important submitted data, you could use `GET` method instead on your search form.

*Controller*

```
public function search(){
    $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
    $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');

    $keyword = $this->input->get('keyword'); // changed to get
    $data['search_data']=$this->Product_model->get_product_keyword($keyword);
    $this->load->view('frontend/search_view',$data);
}
```

*Search_View*

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no cache');
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');; 
echo form_open('search', array('method'=>'get')); ?>
    <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="search">
    <input type="submit" name="search_submit" value="Cari">
<?php echo form_close() ?>

<table>

    <?php foreach($search_data as $men); { ?>
        <tr>
        <?php echo form_open('dashboard/beli');?>
        <td><?php echo ($men->name); ?></td>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>


</table>
```

Comment: when i try this code, didnt remove resubmission and the search page not showing a keyword what i search. then i just try to change $keyword = $this->input->get('keyword'); where 'get' to 'post' again from your code, and yes the search page showing again, but resubmisson didnt gone :(

Comment: did you also change the `form_open` on your view to `get`? if it's still showing this *confirm resubmission* message then there must be another form that trigger this message

Comment: ah, I get it, sorry i've edited the wrong `form_open()` codes, I'll edit it in a moment

Comment: bantu tolong naikin reputasi dong hehe, gua ada pertanyaan lg nih cara menampilkan keyword di halaman carinya. Wait i create a question broo  :D